# How to arrange image and text properly?

Tags: css

I am trying to align an image with some text but my problem is,if the text is too long,the second line goes under the image,and i want it to be aligned with the image too .

This is my code:

```
echo '<li><div class = "imaj">
         <img style = "width:30px;height:35px;"src = "'.$row['image'].'">
      </div><div class = "titl">'.$row['title'].'</div>
      </li>';
```

This is what i want it to look like :
[image]

And this is what it looks like now :

[image: i.stack.imgur.com]

Comment: We really need to see the output HTML & CSS in a demo.

Comment: i eddited the post with the exact image that appears on my website.

Answer (score 1):

there you go:

```
.imaj
{
    float: left;
}

.titl
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjtaLLu9/

Comment: Nice, I'd forgotten about than one.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't seen your code but it seems likely from your images that the `imaj` div is floated left.

That being the case, you merely need to add `margin-left` to your `titl` div.

```css
.imaj {
  float: left;
}
.titl {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="imaj">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-35-35-7.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="titl">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi aliquid quibusdam quos facilis beatae quae architecto reiciendis quam magnam tempore sunt laboriosam repudiandae. Cupiditate eaque id ullam delectus sed mollitia commodi a consectetur
      doloremque ipsam. Dicta porro quisquam vitae labore amet quo ipsam quos exercitationem adipisci et dolorum aut necessitatibus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi aliquid quibusdam quos facilis beatae quae architecto reiciendis quam magnam tempore sunt laboriosam repudiandae. Cupiditate eaque id ullam delectus sed mollitia commodi a consectetur
      doloremque ipsam. Dicta porro quisquam vitae labore amet quo ipsam quos exercitationem adipisci et dolorum aut necessitatibus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the text should be in a div, and give it some margin

```
... <div id="titletext">'.$row['title'].' </div>
```

CSS:

```
#titletext{
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```